# Use macro replacement in Python like C/C++

Tags: python

As we know C/C++ has macro function to do text replacement, here is an example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define FIRST_NAME Print("Moon")
#define FAMILY_NAME Print("Sun")

string Print(string name)
{
    cout << name << endl;
    return name;
}

int main()
{
    string name = FIRST_NAME + FAMILY_NAME; 
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see the `FIRST_NAME` and `FAMILY_NAME` are macros which will be replaced by the function `Print()`.

My question is does Python have a similar feature? Or what can I do to create this kind of feature?

Answer (score 2):

Already in C++ using macros is not considered a good practice. You can get the same performance, and better compiler checking, using functions or templates. These have less risk of repeating side effects, or breaking bugs because of multi-statement macros.

Therefore, a remaining legitimate use for macros, especially in C++, is metaprogramming. e.g The boost preprocessor library.

In python, there are no hard types, only duck types. (If it quacks like a duck, it's enough). It is a dynamic language (versus static), and reduces, if not completely eliminates, the need for macros.

Python has a taste (a philosophy), and it is called being "pythonic". Macros are not pythonic. Just don't use them.

In your case, make functions.

Comment: "there are no hard types, only duck types" unless you're using PEP 484 type annotations.

Answer (score 0):

In Python you can pretty much do achieve *almost* anything you want with its metaclasses (custom behavior of common Python operations on objects), runtime reflection and runtime evaluation.

On the other hand, such an approach is discouraged unless you really need it because it balloons complexity and kills your ability to "statically" understand the code. That is, do not use them unless you are doing things like:

- Dynamic code generation
- Designing a Python-based DSL
- Some kind of framework that needs a bit of magic to look best for users

There is also the possibility of applying any sort of preprocessor to your Python source code, of course, including C's, and including a Python script too.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, python has a similar feature, assignment

```
def MyPrint(name):
    print(name)
    return name

FIRST_NAME = MyPrint("Moon")
FAMILY_NAME = MyPrint("Sun")
```

Note that C++ also has this feature.

Comment: This is not at all the same thing.